# Handling input device plug/unplug while reading from it

Tags: linux, udev

I have a bluetooth remote that is paired with my linux box, when active, this remote is visible at `/dev/input/event13`.

I have a small C program that `open` this device and read directly from it, which works fine.

Now, my problem is that this remote goes to sleep after a few minutes of inactivity and `/dev/input/event13` disappears. It reappears as soon as I press a key on my remote.

I put the output of `udevadm` here: https://gist.github.com/9fff2f0d7edef1050060.

I use the following code (small ruby ext I wrote), to read from the device: https://gist.github.com/b403d538eb6a8627e2bd.

I thought of writing an `udev` rule that would start my program when my remote is added and stop it when it is removed. I read the `udev` documentation, but I couldn't figure it out how to do it. I'm open for suggestion.

Comment: what about using inotify on /dev/input to check for newly created files? So your program never exits, it has to check for file existence, then reads until the device file disappears and the uses inotify to know if the device file reappears.

Comment: This could work, but the problem is that the device name changes from time to time. It was event13 before, now it's event4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and a lot of frustration I did the following:

I put into `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-rmote.rules`

```
KERNEL=="event*", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ACTION=="add|remove", ATTRS{name}=="TiVo Keyboard Remote", RUN+="/home/kuon/handleConnect.rb"
```

And in `handleConnect.rb` I check the `ACTION` environment variable and I start/stop my daemon accordingly. Quite simple in the end and it works well.